# how to handle Horizantal in Polyfill Algorithm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, computer-science

I have a shape, it's look alike this:
[image]
alright, according to [polyfill algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNbkX5bYrtE) to fill the color in the area i need to pass scan lines.
I've provided 6 scan lines.

**Scan 1**: start from `y=-1` like so:
[image]
you know if the previous vertex/point and next vertex/point are on same side, it will not consider as intersection.

```
#list of lines that each line contain [(startpoint, endpoint)]
listLines = [[(4,-1),(4,-2)]]
```

**Scan 2**: start from `y=-2` like so:
[image]
same thing happen in here since **Point13** and **Point15** are in same sides **Point14** is not consider as intersection, as well as **Point9** (cause **Point10** and **Point8** are in same side).

```
#list of lines that each line contain [(startpoint, endpoint)]
listLines = [[(1.7,-2),(6.5,-2)]]
```

**Scan 3**: start from `y=-3` like so:
[image]
but here is the confusion part, now i don't get the Horizontal line.

```
#list of lines that each line contain [(startpoint, endpoint)]
listLines = [[(2.4,-3),(7,-3)],[(9,-3),(10.5,-3)]]
```

**Scan 4**: start from `y=-4` like so:
[image]
and also in here i only get the horizontal lines!!

```
#list of lines that each line contain [(startpoint, endpoint)]
listLines = [[(2,-4),(3,-4)],[(5,-4),(8,-4)]]
```

**Scan 5**: start from `y=-5` like so:
[image]

in here everything work perfectly.

```
#list of lines that each line contain [(startpoint, endpoint)]
listLines = [[(3.5,-5),(5,-5)],[(6,-5),(9.5,-5)]]
```

**Scan 6**: start from `y=-6` like so:
[image]
in here also work perfectly and i get no intersection.

```
#list of lines that each line contain [(startpoint, endpoint)]
listLines = []
```

when i look at polyfill algorithm tutorials/articles or examples, nothing mentioned about how to handle Horizontal lines. anyone has any idea how horizontal lines should be handled?

**Note:** so from my understanding:
if next and previous lines are in same side, Don't count any intersection like so:
[image]
but if next and previous lines are in opposite side like so:
[image]
I have to look at my total number of vertex so far that i collected.

1- If Even, I've to add the first intersection.
2- If Odd, I've to add the last intersection.

but it wont work if lines are laid on the scan line!!. take a look at this example:
[image]

so in order to solve this problem, i come up with a solution that i need to run an optimization and rebuild the shape, simply by finding every line equation and for those that having same equation, remove the share vertex, which would make the shape simple so there wont be any extra vertex on any lines.

that's just do strange that they come so far about scan line algorithm but didn't mention anything about overlapping line equations. isn't it?

Comment: See my explanation for what to do at scan line 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do something inefficiently but correctly.

For every scan line we will start from Point0 go through whole polygon and come back to point0.

At scan line 3

```
Edge (0,1) , point (2.4, -3) -> down-down   (keep the intersection)
Edge (1,2)
Edge (2,3)
Edge (3,4)
Edge (4.5)
Edge (5.6)
Edge (6,7)
Edge (7,8)
Edge (8,9) , point (10.5, -3) -> up-up (keep the intersection)
Edge (9,10), point (9, -3) -> down-left (uh-oh)
Edge (10, 11), points (9, -3) to (7, -3) -> down->left->up (no need to keep any intersection)
Edge (11, 12), point (7, -3) -> left-up (uh-oh)
Edge (12,13)
Edge (13,14)
Edge (14,15)
```

Though you have algorithms to sort the points in O(n) time don't worry about efficiency for now, just apply our favorite quicksort and sort the points along x-axis.

So we get only two points correctly.

At scan line 4

```
Edge (0,1), point (3, -4) -> down-left (uh-oh)
Edge (1,2), points (3,-4) to (2,-4) -> down-left-down (keep point (2,-4))
Edge (2,3), point (2,-4) -> left-down -> (uh-oh)
Edge (3,4), point (5,-4) -> up-right (uh-oh)
Edge (4,5), points (5,-4) to (8,-4) -> up-right-down (ignore)
Edge (5,6), point (8,-4) -> right-down (uh-oh)
Edge (7,8), point (11, -4) -> up-up -> however at top point, (keep point (11,-4).
Edge (8,9), point (11, -4) -> up-up -> however at bottom point, already kept it (ignore)
Edge (9,10)
Edge (10,11)
Edge (11,12)
Edge (12,13)
Edge (13,14)
Edge (14,15)
```

In the worst case the polygon may have lots of windings. Any algorithm should correctly work for it. For example see below:
[image]

There are several way to do this. One for which local information is enough is following: Depending on the turn and which side the interior lies, we can decide which point to take.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment Shreesh, i've added some extra information to my question, let me know about your thoughts, also here http://bernardrouhi.blogspot.my/2016/02/polyfill-algorithm.html i've explained almost every steps that i took.

Comment: @Bear, Odd even formula won't work unless  you know  where you have started from: above the scan line or below the scan line. I give an alternative mechanism, we always know that interior is to our left as we are going anticlockwise. I assume polygon boundary does not crosses itself.

Comment: Any way  odd even is a well known way to determine which side the interior is.

Comment: Thanks for respond and explanation Shreesh, The reason i don't want to involve shape clockwise or anti-clockwise with algorithm, is because user can do lots of unexpected things, and they can simply make the shape cross it self, and i want to make sure the algorithm doesn't cause any error/problem, Yes, you are right, Odd and Even idea wont work unless, i line them up and test the lines from lowest x axis to highest x axis. but i need to try it out and see if this theory actually work.

Comment: Also there would be problems with degeneracies and overlapping lines, if they are allowed.